# Spring MVC + StreamingResponseBody - exception causes HTTP OK

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, exception, streaming

I've got a strange problem regarding StreamingReponseBody in my spring MVC controller. The simple controller code:

```
    @RestController
    public class ServerController {

    @GetMapping("test")
    StreamingResponseBody test(HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setContentType("text/csv");
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"test.csv\"");


        return outputStream -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
                outputStream.write("Hello".getBytes());
                outputStream.write("\n".getBytes());
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (true) {
                throw new RuntimeException("wrong");
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
                outputStream.write("Hello2".getBytes());
                outputStream.write("\n".getBytes());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Plus just a controller advice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleInternalServerError(Exception exception) {
        System.out.println("Unexpected error " + exception);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exception.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

}

When I delete the throw clause it works like a charm. When I input the URL */test to browser I can see that I can download the file test.csv. It is streamed correctly for a while and I get a 200 HTTP code and I can view the file.

However throwing exception causes the code to do some strange things. I don't receive a 500 HTTP code, but a 200 HTTP code. At the end of the stream i get a "wrong" text (exception text o_O)... What's happening here? Why I don't get a 500 HTTP code. The endpoint is sending not full data, but it says that it's ok despite exceptions. Or should I use some other streaming mechanism because this one is faulty?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Correct my understanding. You started sending data using stream so you (I guess) can't say at some moment "wait, delete data I've already sent and change http status [which is set to 200 probably just before started sending some data]". So when exception occurred Spring reuses OutputStream and puts data from:

`return new ResponseEntity<>(exception.getMessage()`

into the same OutputStream.

One suggestion could be to wrap code which can potentially throw an exception in try-catch and use `IOUtils.closeQuietly` but effect is that you will get 5000x of Hello and end of stream (so still 200 http status, the data you send correctly is on client side, but without `wrong` at the end)

Example:

```
if (true) {
    try {
        throw new RuntimeException("wrong");
     } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream); #apache
        throw e;
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. So is there a more error-aware solution for returning some dynamic data to the client? Firstly stream the response and then send the headers or return everything only when everything is ok?

Comment: Nobody knows the answer?

Comment: Still no answer for this? I am also facing the same issue now.